# unit testing express route controller with multiple external API requests

Tags: unit-testing, express, nock

in my unit tests I need to mock some http requests.

```
const getDashboardData = (req, res) => {
  const activeListings = articlesLib.getLiveArticles(req.user.id)
  const soldThisMonthPromise = articlesLib.getSoldArticles(req.user.id, {})
  const userDrafts = articlesLib.getDrafts(req.user.id)

  return Promise.all([activeListings, soldThisMonthPromise, userDrafts])
  .then((data) => {
    res.render(`${__dirname}/home`, {
      viewData: data
    })
  })
}

router.get('/', getDashboardData)
```

Each request from articleLib has the same url, but uri is different. I wanted to mock it with nock, but it doesn't support multiple mock for the same base url. Is there any tool that mock a response when given http request is detected?